# Why can't I use a .dev address in my Windows hosts file for my development server?

Tags: windows, dns, hosts

I tried to edit my Windows hosts file to route a bogus domain name to an IP address on my Local Area Network.

Why does this entry work:

```
webdev 10.10.1.100
```

But this does not? It causes every browser to "HTTPS" it.

```
web.dev 10.10.1.100
```

Answer (score 2):

`.dev` is a Google TLD and is in the HSTS preloading list.

In short, that means all browsers will only do HTTPS call to any such names, never HTTP.

So don't use those names, at least not without an HTTPS webserver and the appropriate X509 certificate for the name, otherwise the browser will complain of mismatch and not even connect.

More generally, for local needs, do not "invent" names and TLDs. You will only get problems. Register once for all a domain, in any TLD, like `example.com` (but obviously not that), and then use it as suffix of any of the internal names you need. That solves all problems both now and in the future.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I know those are frowned upon around here nowadays. I was able to settle on webdev.local

Comment: @suchislife I recommend against using `.local` either because this TLD is reserver for mDNS needs. In all cases, see last paragraph in my answer, this is the best route to follow.